# sharePDF by email without saving

Tags: android, email, mobile, request, share

I'm receiving a PDF from a server request, actually I can show it without saving it. The problem comes when I want to share the file without saving it, if I select "share by e-mail" a toast appears telling me that it's not possible to attach empty files. Any help please?

```
        String filePathPDF = Constants.URL_GROUP_LIST + myGroup.getIdGpr();
        File filePDF = new File(filePathPDF);
        Uri pathPDF = Uri.fromFile(filePDF);

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
        String to[] = {};
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathPDF);

        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Lista del grupo " + myGroup.getGrade() + myGroup.getGroupLetter());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,filePathPDF);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar lista vía e-mail..."));
```

What I have in filePathPDF is the URL to the PDF.

Comment: You cannot make a File object from an url.

Comment: Ok, so, there is no other way than saving it?

Comment: Yes. Indeed... You do.